# How are Bulletproofs similar / different from Bulletproofs++?

Tags: transaction-size, bulletproofs

I hear references to Bulletproofs++ in Monero, however I have not seen any clear explanation of how they improve upon "standard" [Bulletproofs](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1066.pdf).  Can someone provide a simple explanation of the differences especially with regards to transaction size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I hear references to Bulletproofs++ in Monero,

It's actually Bulletproofs+ (note the single +) and has recently been [merged](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/commit/bd27debb2d480845acdd20c4d02509d55fd4f188) to the master branch, so should be in the next major release.

> however I have not seen any clear explanation of how they improve upon "standard" Bulletproofs.

See https://www.getmonero.org/2020/12/24/Bulletproofs+-in-Monero.html

Most notably:

> The new construction would make transactions smaller, faster for wallets to generate, and faster for network participants to verify.

And for the detail:

https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/735

Comment: Am I reading this correctly that proofs are 576 bytes then?

Comment: For proving a _single_ value, yes.